# Sum Converges or Diverges?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions

I am running MMA 13.1.0.0 on Windows 10 - x86.

Is there any way to get Mathematica to conclude that this sum converges (maybe it needs some additional input)?

```
  Sum[1/n^(2 + Cos[n]^2), {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

I also tried

```
  SumConvergence[1/n^(2 + Cos[n]^2), n]
```

Neither returns a result, but it can be determined using a direct comparison.

Aside: [*Wolfram Alpha's*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+from+n%3D1+to+infinity+of+1%2F%28n%5E%282%2B%28cos%28n%29%29%5E2%29%29) result says it diverges, but is that incorrecct?

Comment: W|A's result is incorrect, yes.

Comment: `Sum[1/n^3, {n, 1, Infinity}] < Inactive[Sum][1/n^(2 + Cos[n]^2), {n, 1, Infinity}] < Sum[1/n^2, {n, 1, Infinity}]`

Comment: The tests that work with the similar $\frac{1}{n^2}$  were the Raab test and the integral test (in the list of method's for `SumConvergence`). However, when I explicitly ask for the limit for the Raab test, Mathematica could not find the limit. Mathematica can not find the integral either but I do not know if that is how it determines whether the integral converges. With a $n^{\cos(n)^2}$ I am not sure any of the methods on this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests) that do not rely on inequalities would work in Mathematica.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the converging sum:

```
s1= Sum[1/n^2, {n, 1, Infinity}]
(* Pi^2/6*)
```

As 1/n^2 >= 1/n^(2 + Cos[n]^2) the above sum is an upper bound to

```
s2= Sum[1/n^(2 + Cos[n]^2), {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

and as s2 only contains positive terms, s2 must converge.

However, it may be that there is no simple expression for the sum. But we can get a numerical result from:

```
NSum[1/n^(2 + Cos[n]^2), {n, 1, Infinity}]

(* 1.39686 *)
```